# Microsoft Bot Framework 403 BotDisabledByAdmin

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Our bot, uploaded on a customer's tenant as a Microsoft Teams **tenant** sideloaded/custom app, then installed into different Teams teams, is getting a 403 "BotDisabledByAdmin" error when we make a Microsoft Bot Framework REST API request to send a message to users.

The bot was installed successfully and correctly messaged users. However, when attempting to message a new user who had not previously interacted with the bot, the error above occurred.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this? We have looked at app permission policies & org-wide settings and everything should be OK.

**Edit**
I believe I have figured out the issue. The app is only allowed for certain users in the "Permission Policies" tab, which indicates these users can **install** the app. Actually, that's not what it does: it allows users not only to install, but also to **interact** with the app. So, if a user has a policy where "Custom apps" is turned off, that means they cannot message the app and the app cannot message them. I would really suggest Microsoft to fix this dialog in the Permissions tab, because it is very misleading. Installing is not the same thing as interacting.
[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies)

We are now testing with "Custom apps" turned on in Permission Policies for all users, given that there's usually a propagation delay of about 24 hours I will give an update tomorrow.

Our issue now is that while we want all users that are part of a team the bot is installed in to be able to use the bot, we do not want all users to be able to install the bot to a team. It is a tenant app, so any user can view it. How can we prevent users from **installing** the app to new teams but allow users to **interact** (e.g. message privately, click buttons, receive messages from) with the app that is part of their team?

Comment: Are you trying to send a proactive message? If so, and the user has not previously interacted with the bot, how did you get a conversationid, and serviceurl?

Comment: The app is installed in a team that contains the user

Comment: so can you explain what you mean about "messaging" a user? Do you mean messaging them privately, 1-1, or just @mentioning them in the team chat itself?

Comment: Messaging them privately

Comment: ah ok, I figured as much. In that case, yes, the user has to actually have the app physically installed. You can do that either by having them install it themselves, or programatically via the Graph, but then your app would need appropriate tenant permissions of course. Installing via the Graph might help get around allowing them to install it to -other- teams though

Comment: Thanks Hilton, I'm not sure what "installing via the Graph" means, do you have any documentation on this? It's still unclear to me how I can have a tenant app, installable by some users, but usable by all users that have access to it through a shared team.

Comment: Sure, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-add-teamsappinstallation?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http . Notice it's on the 'beta' endpoint, so not 'officially' live + supported functionality